# html table extend vertically not horizontally

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I want to extend my table vertically not horizontally.
please any one help me to solve this.. here is the design of table I want.

[image: design of table that I want to create]

Comment: do you have a code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this will help you to make your desire table.

```
<table class="table-bordered text-center" cellpadding="10">
<col>
<colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
<colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
<tr>
    <th rowspan="100" scope="rowgroup">Fourniture</th>
    <th rowspan="2" scope="rowgroup"></th>
    <th colspan="4" scope="colgroup">2017</th>
    <th colspan="4" scope="colgroup">2016</th>
    <th rowspan="2" scope="rowgroup">total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="1" scope="colgroup">jan</th>
    <th colspan="1" scope="colgroup">feb</th>
    <th colspan="1" scope="colgroup">mar</th>
    <th colspan="1" scope="colgroup">mar</th>
    <th colspan="1" scope="colgroup">april</th>
    <th colspan="1" scope="colgroup">may</th>
    <th colspan="1" scope="colgroup">june</th>
    <th colspan="1" scope="colgroup">july</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Board Games</th>
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Teddy Bears</th>
    <td>50,000</td>
    <td>30,000</td>
    <td>100,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Board Games</th>
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Board Games</th>
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Board Games</th>
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Board Games</th>
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
</tr>
```

Here is a running example : https://jsfiddle.net/Haider_alee/1vunp5bo/1/.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this, Just change the height of column and remains width as it is.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th height="100">Month</th>
    <th height="100">Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what You want but try put in CSS something like:

```
  table tr th{
     width:100px !important;
     min-width:100px!important; //optional
     max-width:100px !important; //optional
     height:auto;
  }
```

and this should work.